# 7zip command line powershell extract and view txt compressed

Tags: powershell, view, extract, 7zip, txt

I use the command to extract only the folders containing a specific name, but now I want to know if it is possible to make 7zip extract only .txt files that have at least one word of my choice in them. Like for example

```
& 'C:\Program Files\7-zip7z.exe' x *.* -o(directory) *.txt (word I want to have inside the .txt e.g. password)
```

I used this command as an example of what I wanted it to look like, but in reality it only works for extracting just the filename
If you also have another way to do this with compressed files other than 7zip, I will be happy with any help

Comment: This is doable using .NET APIs not sure if 7zip supports it

Comment: From their own site (https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract_full.htm): `7-Zip doesn't use the system wildcard parser. 7-Zip doesn't follow the archaic rule by which *.* means any file. 7-Zip treats *.* as matching the name of any file that has an extension. To process all files, you must use a * wildcard.`